# External application is not getting open when I select an application coming from UIDocumentInteractionController "presentOpenInMenuFromRect" method

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

[image]

when I select Dropbox from the list nothing is happening. Here is the code:

```
- (void)openIn:(NSURL *)fileFullPath {
    docController = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:fileFullPath];
    [docController setDelegate:self];

    BOOL isOpen = [docController presentPreviewAnimated:YES];

    if (isOpen == NO) {
        BOOL isOpenIn = [docController presentOpenInMenuFromRect:CGRectMake(300, 300, 100, 100) inView:self.view animated:NO];

        if(isOpenIn == NO) {
            return ;
        }
    }
}
```